# LDAP Query the global catalog

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to make an LDAP query for get all the user member of a group. The problem is that this group is populated with user from multiple AD domains and I've to get all the members user with a singe query.

According to [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc978012.aspx) I can reach my goal by querying the Global Catalog.

```
ldapsearch -x -W -H "ldap://mydomain.local:3268" -D "CN=myuser,OU=Applicative Users,OU=Users,OU=myou,DC=mydomain,DC=local" -b " "  '(&(objectclass=user)(memberof=CN=mygroup,OU=Groups,OU=myou,DC=mydomain,DC=local))
```

This query return only the users member of "mygroup" that resides on the domain "mydomain"

No info are retrieved for the users that come from trusted domains.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check out the last paragraph of the https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978012.aspx and see if your query fits the conditions. And does myuser have rights in other domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global catalog only stores group memberships for universal groups. You also won't get transitive (e.g. nested) group memberships with this query. You can use the LDAP in-chain matching operator if you need to get these also.

Comment: You should provide the OID and an example (syntax) for that.